# How to add to the commerce order the author's email? Cannot theme nor add anything to it!

Tags: entities, commerce, theming

I have this order at /admin/commerce/orders/oid/view

By default, the order won't display the user's email nor username, so I wanted to know how to access them and printed them out.

I created a tpl file called: **page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php** and typed into it:

```
print "<pre>";  
$vars = get_defined_vars();
print_r($vars);  
print "</pre>";
```

I got this result (it's trimmed, but you can read that the uid is 76 -there's no name though-, and the user's email is demo@example.com):

```
Array
(
    [template_file] => themes/seven/page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php
    [variables] => Array
        (
            [page] => Array
                (
                    [#show_messages] => 1
                    [#theme] => page
                    [content] => Array
                        (
                            [devel_execute_php] => Array
                                (
                                    [execute] => Array
                                        (
                                            [#type] => fieldset
                                            [#title] => Execute PHP Code
                                            [#collapsible] => 1
                                            [#collapsed] => 1
                                            ...

                            [system_main] => Array
                                (
                                    [commerce_order] => Array
                                        (
                                            [2340] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [commerce_line_items] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [#theme] => field
                                                            [#weight] => 0
                                                            [#title] => Line items
                                                            [#access] => 1
                                                            [#label_display] => hidden
                                                            [#view_mode] => administrator
                                                            [#language] => und
                                                            [#field_name] => commerce_line_items
                                                            [#field_type] => commerce_line_item_reference
                                                            [#field_translatable] => 0
                                                            [#entity_type] => commerce_order
                                                            [#bundle] => commerce_order
                                                            [#object] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [order_number] => 2340
                                                                    [revision_id] => 7766
                                                                    [revision_uid] => 1
                                                                    [mail] => demo@example.com
                                                                    [status] => pending
                                                                    [log] => 
                                                                    [revision_timestamp] => 1418617139
                                                                    [revision_hostname] => 190.191.78.169
                                                                    [data] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [order_id] => 2340
                                                                    [type] => commerce_order
                                                                    [uid] => 76
                                                                    [created] => 1409009029
                                                                    [changed] => 1418617139
                                                                    [hostname] => 201.255.45.102
                                                                    [commerce_line_items] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        ....
```

After [reading](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/print-out-a-drupal-commerce-field-only-if-it-has-a-value)-[some](https://www.drupal.org/node/1807072)-[information](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/drupal-commerce-how-to-theme-product-field?rq=1)-[around](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/DC)-[the web](https://www.drupal.org/node/1238606), and the book [Drupal 7 Module Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849511160) (chapters 3 and 4), I tried (unsuccessfully) all these:

```
print render($content['#object']);
print render($content['#object']['mail']);
print render($content['#object']['uid']);
print render($variables['content']['#object']['uid']);
echo render($content['content']['#object']['uid']);
print render($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['commerce_order']['2340']['commerce_line_items']['#object->mail']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
print render(commerce_order_load(2340));
```

I'm thinking the user id will be something like

```
$order = commerce_order_load(2340);
$order['uid'];
```

from there you can do

```
$customer = user_load($order['uid']);
print render($customer->name);
print render($customer->email);
```

But try to print commerce_order_load and take a look at that output first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! commerce_oredr_load() is getting me an error Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in .../themes/seven/page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php on line 9 (the function line).
The thing is that the documentation (http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_load/7) says it should be the order id! (like: commerce_order_load($order_id)). I've tried with and without quotes.

Comment: That is why I said 2340, because based on the output you posted the order id is 2340. Do you have the devel module installed by chance? It includes a module that allows you to run php code from inside Drupal. It is a great tool for things like this. Try commerce_order_load(2340)->uid

Comment: Yes, I've tried echo commerce_order_load(2340)->uid; and printed out 76 (which is the uid)... The order number is correct...

Comment: So you know how to get the uid. Once you have the uid to display the email it is `user_load($uid)->email`. I just realized though, that with the default view that the commerce module comes with, you can add the email field for the user. Which would be much easier than creating a custom tpl

Comment: Thanks! (the only thing left is to replace 2340 with the order id, is there a way to do that within the tpl file?). As my ultimate goal is to completely change the way the order looks like, I think I'm going to need a tpl sooner or later...

Comment: I think when your on the orders page there is a variable $order for each order. You may have to loop through all of the orders on the page. You could probably use `commerce_order_load_multiple()` to do that. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23816/commerce-get-product-ids-from-order for a guide.